# Do I really need a well?

Tags: stardew-valley

You can purchase a Well that allows you to fill up your watering can, but I find myself with patches of water on my farm and rivers flowing all around me.

Is there ever an instance where this water will not be available and a well would help me, or would I just be buying this for the convenience of placing a water source where I want it?

Comment: If I was to hazard a guess, I'd say it was for the latter - I can't find any clear cut information on it's purpose, though.

Comment: @Sean Yeah I think I'm agreeing with what you're finding so far.

Comment: I would assume that, without a definitive answer, is that it's just to become a time saver for travelling across the farm.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need a well. You can always fill your watering can up at the ponds on your farm, but depending on how your crops are spread out a well placed well can save you a lot of time.

Comment: ...although by the time you have that many crops, you'll probably be using sprinklers anyway.